# jquery focus with checkbox on ipad not working

Tags: jquery, ipad, jquery-mobile

I have a simple form where user have to select checkbox before submitting the form and if that checkbox not select focus should go to that checkbox. its working fine on all the browsers but its not working in iPad. Any idea what could be the cause?

```
<form name="test" action="" method="post"> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="terms" id="terms"/> 
    <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="return check();"/> 
</form> 
<script> 
    function check(){ 
        var ischecked = document.getElementById("terms").checked; 
        if(!ischecked) { 
            document.getElementById("terms").focus(); 
            return false; 
        } 
    } 
</script>
```

thanks

Comment: <form name="test" action="" method="post">
  <input type="checkbox" name="terms" id="terms"/>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="return check();"/>
  </form>
  <script>
  function check(){
   var ischecked =  document.getElementById("terms").checked;
  if(!ischecked)
  { 
  document.getElementById("terms").focus();
   return false;
  }


  }


  
  </script>

Comment: Have you tried to add `return true;` at the end of the function?

Answer (score 0):

Late reply, but I ran into the same issue.  It looks like mobile safari does not like to focus on checkboxes.  What worked for me was using scrollIntoView() and then displaying a validation message (using Jquery validate).  The element is not actually focused, but for the user will immediately see the validation message and know what action is required which worked for my needs.

```
document.getElementById('terms').scrollIntoView();
```